# VueJS 2 typeahead callback method

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, typeahead, vue-strap

I'm using the Typeahead component from vue-strap,

Am trying to make a callback after i hit on the selection which will stamp the data into my input texts.

Once i hit enter, inventoryName and inventoryId is successfully stamped in but the inventoryCode component is reset.

How to prevent it from reset or did i do anything wrong? As i can see from console.log it has the value.

```
<typeahead v-model="inventoryCode" placeholder="Inventory code..." async="{{url('api/inventory')}}/" :template="inventorySearch" :on-hit="inventoryCallBack"></typeahead>
<input type="text" name="inventory_name" id="inventory_name" class="form-control" v-model="inventoryName" readonly />

new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        components:{Typeahead},
        data: {
            'inventoryCode': '',
            'inventoryName': '',
            'inventoryId': '',
            'inventorySearch': '<div style="min-width:150px;"><b>@{{item.inventory_name}}</b></div><div>@{{item.inventory_code}}</div><div>@{{item.inventory_short_desc}}</div>'
        },
methods:{
    inventoryCallBack: function(item){
                    console.log(item.inventory_code);
                    this.inventoryCode = item.inventory_code;
                    this.inventoryName = item.inventory_name;
                    this.inventoryId = item.id;
                    console.log(this.inventoryCode);
                },
}
});
```

Comment: firstly, `inventoryCallBack` function should be in methods property.

Comment: @SrinivasDamam sorry, typo, it is in a method prop. Other model is being assigned values but not inventoryCode.

Comment: You have a capital "T" in `components: { Typeahead }`. Shouldn't it be lower case?

Answer (score 0):

```
inventoryCallBack: function(item){
                    console.log(item.inventory_code);
                    this.inventoryCode = item.inventory_code;
                    this.inventoryName = item.inventory_name;
                    this.inventoryId = item.id;
                    return item.inventory_code
                },
```

This should do the trick, missed out this part.